# Angular JS Trying create a clone of header, but directives no longer work on clone

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

Trying to do something like this

```
    angular.element('.header').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.header').addClass('cloned').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin-top', '0').css('z-index', '500').css('padding-top', '15px').css('padding-bottom', '16px').removeClass('original').hide();
    angular.element('.cloned').show();
    angular.element('.original').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    angular.element('.original').addClass('orginal-header');
```

And it creates a clone of my header for a sticky header solution, but then I notice the directives I have on a link in the header i.e. a help link which opens/closes a popup menu no longer works.

I.e In my header I have this

```
<div class="dropdown pull-right" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-menu dropdown-toggle" href dropdown-toggle> Help? </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a ui-sref="help">Get Help?</a></li>
          <li><a href open-support-modal>Report an Issue</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

I have a click event on dropdown-toggle which no longer triggers on the copied header.

Any ideas ?

Comment: you need to attach the event again after cloning is finished.

Comment: So I need to reattach the dropdown-toggle directive on the help link ? If I look at the html of both headers in source they are both identical just the original has the working directive and the cloned header directives does nothing

Comment: I think maybe you need to compile the HTML code using `$compile`.

Comment: This might solve it: `var element = angular.element(".cloned"); $compile(element.contents())($scope);`

Comment: @OmriAharon I tried that         var element = angular.element(".cloned"); 
        $compile(element.contents())($scope); but got an error $compile is not a function

Comment: Yeah make sure you're injecting the `$compile` service into your controller/directive/wherever it is you're doing the above code.

Comment: oh ye ofcourse, but then now get an error Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- stickyDirective

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73414/discussion-between-omri-aharon-and-stevieb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are modifying the DOM, you have to inform angular that it needs to take a second look at things. That's what the `$compile` service is for. Add this code after your cloning code:

```
var element = angular.element(".cloned"); 
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```